# How do I Manage an Array of Writables?

Tags: svelte

I have a randomly sized array of objects each containing a `name` property and a `state` writable property. I would like to reactively access the values in the stores.

I tried below at first, but Svelte doesn't allow you to use stores in this way.

```html
{#each pins as pin}
    {@const state = pin.state}
    <p>{pin.name} - {$state}</p>
    <br/>
{/each}
```

I need to do something with `pins` in my script block but what I need to do isn't clear. How should I do this?

Comment: What is the type of `pins`? Is it a writable containing an array, is it an array of writables, or is it a writable array of writables?

Comment: @LeoDog896 The exact types are `Pins: Array<Pin>` `Pin: { name: string, state: Writable<boolean> }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably two approaches:

- Extract the contents of the `#each` to a separate component so you can define a top-level variable for the store, which can be passed in via a property, either individually or as the entire `pin`. If the whole `pin` is passed in you need a separate assignment to make the store top-level.
- Resolve the value of all stores, e.g. via a derived store that maps the array. This is a bit convoluted and might have some overhead.

Example to illustrate the latter:

```html
<script>
    import { writable, derived, get } from 'svelte/store';
    
    let items = [
        { id: 1, state: writable('state 1') },
        { id: 2, state: writable('state 2') },
        { id: 3, state: writable('state 3') },
    ];
    
    $: resolvedItems = derived(
        items.map(i => i.state),
        // `get` is not reactive, but `derived` is
        () => items.map(item => ({ ...item, state: get(item.state) })),
    );
</script>

{#each $resolvedItems as { id, state }}
    <div>{id} - {state}</div>
{/each}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7e127b82436445fba2fd7be26b77a272?version=3.53.1)

(Would recommend the extraction approach.)